# Developing 32 bit application and using it in 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: compiling, 32-bit, c++

I would like to develop 32 bit c++ applications on an Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit machine and use it on both 32 bit and 64 bit machines. One of the main difficulties I face is that I use some library which use 'unsigned long'. I want 'unsigned long' to take only 4 bytes to work the application properly. How can I compile 32 bit application on 64 bit machine?

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: The fact that it assumes `unsigned long` is 4 bytes is just bad. Is it doing anything with assembly or pointer manipulation? Are you sure the application doesn't work as expected when compiled for 64-bit?

Comment: @saiarcot895 yea he edited the post a minute after i posted my comment.  And yes in any API you will need multiple library dependencies to write in 32 bit on 64 bit anywhere.

Comment: Can you modify the source code of the library?